# Mac Book Air 10.10.3 strange artifacts on screen

Tags: display, macbook-air

I have Mac Book Air 10.10.3 and on the screen there is strange behavior when moving/changing windows. See the following photo:

[image: photo]

This is solid pink (in Photoshop) but the screen sometimes shows me colors like on the photo.

Sometimes colors are pale, otherwise they are vivid. How can I set colors solid?
It appears on screen and I took a photo of this, because a screenshot doesn't show this problem.

Comment: This looks like a panel fault to me, as you say it doesnt appear in screenshots.
Do you get the same effect if you plug into an external monitor? (unlikely)

Comment: Yes. There's no difference with of without external monitor.

Comment: Oh right.... That rules out the panel then. So I'd say reinstall the video driver, failing that's it's likely a hardware fault